# Equivariant vector bundle structure on the tangent bundle of compact Riemann surfaces with non trivial action on the base space,

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, vector-bundles, group-actions

Let $M_{g}$ be the compact Riemann surface with $g\geq 2$.
Is there an infinit group $G$ with an equivariant action on the pair $(TM_{g}, M_{g})$ such that the action on the fibers preserves the inner product, moreover there is no a $G$-fixed point on the base space.
Recall that a $G$-fixed point is a point $p$ with $g.p=p$ for all  $g\in G$.

This question is a remedy of my previous post bellow

https://mathoverflow.net/questions/252271/equivariant-bundle-structure-on-the-tangent-bundle-of-compact-riemann-surfaces